# How to get mutual friends between two users though Facebbok SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

**I'm getting below response**

> context =     {
>                id = dXNlcl9jb250ZAXh0OgGQBzZClTeqLPWlrfXhrRaRW9p9DqJ1JlGbVrKdKTcRs5N3uTiLEv0eodSwGMLnVQ3KHhbYHKxZCHR6j0wwCXfASlTLEvlHo745AGAGMuQ5AgcnIZD;
>                };
>                id = 1654104691364391;
>                }

**I'm using below code to get**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(fbTokenID)", parameters: ["fields": "context.fields(mutual_friends.limit(8))"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            UtilityClass .removeActivityIndicator()
            if (error == nil){
                PRINT(result!) 
            } else {
                PRINT(error.debugDescription)
                PRINT(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#friends-4-4:

> **Mutual Friends**
>   The Mutual Friends API is no longer available.

Facebook has removed this, there is no way to get what you want any more.

Comment: you can create an intersection of those on your own, but the mutual friends api is gone.

Comment: @iOSLifee and what does that have to do with the mutual friends endpoint?

Comment: @CBroe No other way to get Mutual friends?

Comment: No, no other way. (Apart from what luschn said, about doing it yourself with the data that you still can get.)

Comment: @CBroe can I use this to get mutual friends
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application-context/friends_using_app/

Comment: Don’t know - test it and see what you get …?